# Access denied when hosting

Tags: php

it was fine when I use localhost but when I uploaded for hosting this lines appeared

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.2.33' (using password: NO) in /home/u957908988/public_html/conf/config.php on line 7

why am I denied of access?

Comment: Try connecting through the `mysqli_` or PDO API. Your hosting service may no longer have the `mysql_` functions available.

Comment: show your full code then, or use `localhost` - hard to say without seeing actual code

Comment: May be the remote login is not enabled for the mysql server.

Comment: this is my code :

`code`<?php
$host= 'uphaz.hol.es';
$user='u957908988_uphaz';
$pass='';
$db='u957908988_uphaz';

$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
$dbselect=mysqli_select_db($db,$connect);


?>`code`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you entered wrong password. Please enter correct password in database connect code. If you have phpmyadmin option, try to login to your database using the user name and password provided in the `mysql_connect`. And makes sure it is correct.